# Can I embed Google Street View into AFrame?

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-street-view, aframe, webvr

I'd like to recreate the [Geoguesser](https://geoguessr.com/) street view game in VR. Although I understand the game is more complex than simply viewing Google Street View, I want to understand whether any work on the matter exists now. Even simply embedding Google Street View in VR would be helpful, even if it's not a solution in AFrame.

Has anyone tried this before? Or can anyone speak to embedding Google Street View in VR?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to get the Street View panorama image in its full equirectangular glory so that you could then render it in A-Frame or your WebVR framework of choice.

There are a few methods to extract Street View panoramas in this answer:
[How to get the original panorama image by panoid in google street view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40989418/how-to-get-the-original-panorama-image-by-panoid-in-google-street-view)

This seemed to be the best option based on an A-Frame Slack chat:
https://github.com/mattdesl/google-panorama-equirectangular

Here's a recent WebVR project that, while not exactly the same, appears to make use of some of the same tech:
https://speaktogo.withgoogle.com/#