# How to get the original panorama image by panoid in google street view?

Tags: google-street-view, panoramas

I have got the reference of getting the panorama image by panoid but its giving me only the thumbnail image but I want an original panorama image directly from streetview.

The link is given below what I have got
http://cbk0.google.com/cbk?output=thumbnail&w=500&h=500&panoid=-_0l0tU3lKz0JtaEsqJk7w

Please help me out to get the original panorama image not the thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no official API to download the full panorama. There are many tools that you can use.

Windows Tool:
http://www.purebasic.fr/english/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=50248

NodeJS: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-streetview

https://github.com/mattdesl/google-panorama-equirectangular

Chrome plugin: 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pano-fetch/ggmfokbjchlhboclfngkneflhkopebbh?hl=en

**Note:** The thumbnail url that you are using is also an unofficial way. You should use their API to load streetview thumbnail. Please refer: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro