# Does the Google Street View API support retrieving a full 360 equi-rectangualr image?

Tags: google-street-view, 360-panorama

The docs are not clear on this as they mention fov and viewport suggesting a portion of the entire spherical image.

Does the Google Street View API support retrieving the **entire** 360 degree equi-rectangular (lat/lon) image?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could download separate panorama tiles and pack them together of use a third party tool (ex: https://istreetview.com/) and get the entire 360 degree image.

Another option would be to code the above functionality by yourself by using Google StreetView Image API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro). To be honest, I did not try this myself, but through the API you should be able to retrieve all parts of the image and then stitch it back into equirectangular panorama.

This might give you more info:
[How to get the original panorama image by panoid in google street view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40989418/how-to-get-the-original-panorama-image-by-panoid-in-google-street-view)

EDIT: While searching a way to overcome the fact that Google StreetView app doesn;t work as marketed, I found another third party service able to retrieve photos https://gothru.co/

Comment: I am not quite understanding you answer. Are you saying there is API to download all sections of a cubic map or something similar? What is the API istreetview.com is using?

Comment: It's called Google StreetView Image API
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro

Comment: @dugla I am looking for something similar, did u have any success in retrieving the equi-rectangular image?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by making use of the `FOV` and `heading` options within the API.

Take particular note of the `heading` param.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=640x640&location=51.52551,-0.08853&fov=120&heading=0&key=YOUR_KEY

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=640x640&location=51.52551,-0.08853&fov=120&heading=120&source=outdoor&key=YOUR_KEY

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=640x640&location=51.52551,-0.08853&fov=120&heading=240&key=YOUR_KEY
```

By making these three separate API calls you will receive the 360 image sliced into three parts.

You can then use something like [node blend](https://github.com/mapbox/node-blend) to combine them and voila you have a 360 panoramic image!