# Add Google maps/Google Earth VR to React360 app

Tags: react-360

Am pretty new to `react360`. I would like to integrate google maps with react360, preferably google earth VR if possible.

I have tried out [google-maps-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react), but it doesn't work on react360 but only made to React. I have no idea how to use [GoogleEarthVR](https://vr.google.com/earth/) or [Google Street View](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro) or google maps API on React 360.

The react360 app should load a location on a street view or earth VR and move around it once you select a preferred location.

Comment: You might have better luck with A-Frame, see this article https://blog.mozvr.com/introducing-a-terrain/ and this answer on SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/43950171/1333383

Comment: Thanks @Valentin, will look more into A-Frame and how the solutions you've shared work